# Price of eggs have increased... Still minhag to throw away all eggs that have something resembling a spot?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, eggs, poultry

Had a thought while reading OU article about checking eggs for blood spots  ([this was the article by the way](https://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/eggs-and-blood-spots/))

The article cites Rav Feinstein zt"l for the minhag to check every egg and discard anything that looks like a spot because "eggs are not expensive and a person does not incur any significant loss" even though mei'ikar hadin an unfertilized egg would have no actual possibility of true blood spot.

My thought was this: with inflation of food prices, does that affect  the logic behind this minhag? The average price of a dozen eggs at my local grocery store (Ralph's in the Los Angeles area) is around $8 and goes up to $12. Throwing eggs away certainly feels like, well, painful.

Other question is if I have my own flock of hens and there are no roosters, is there still a minhag or any logical reason to check the eggs?

Comment: Less than 1% of white eggs have blood spots, which means the minhag costs less than 1 cent per egg.

Comment: @shmosel That is misusing averages. The cost of throwing away an egg is 1/12 what you paid for the dozen.

Comment: @shmosel Reb Moshe says specifically that the cost of an egg is irrelevant, so there's no reason not to keep the *minhag* going. Which is pretty *mephurash* like the question that Reb Moshe would not say that if the cost of eggs is not insignificant.

Comment: @N.T. I would argue that the cost of the egg is more than just 1/12th. Because if it's your last egg then you can't get another one without paying for 12/12 eggs.

Comment: Blood spots are not that common. The important thing would be not being overly strict and throwing away your eggs when it's unnecessary. Only bright red blood spots that are obviously blood require the egg to be thrown out. Any spotting in the egg which is brown or other coloring would not necessitate the egg be discarded.